# Mass conversion of images to GIF

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

I have created over 600 images from a simulation I ran. I want to convert these images into a GIF format. Can you provide me a way to do so and one that allows me to show each image for >1second.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ImageMagick can do it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1034104):

```
convert -delay 100 -loop 0 image*.png animation.gif
```

Replace `image*.png` with whatever your images are named.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Beware that you'll need a lot of RAM for 600 files.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Each image is 1.3MB and I've created them all from scratch in PPM format. I mistyped earlier; I need each image to only play for roughly a quarter of a second. On a side note I've got 16GB of RAM.

Comment: I just got it working and it is running with no problem! This is so perfect thanks for your help!!!

Comment: If you want to resize your final GIF you can add ex. "-resize 800x600" to convert and it uses less RAM, but still pretty high :(

Comment: My images had a transparent background so I had to add `dispose 2` to remove the previous frames.

Answer (score 2):

## Converseen

...is a good GUI tool for converting and compressing images. It might be able to help you here. I'm aware of the ImageMagick answer, this is a GUI solution.

Its website is http://converseen.sourceforge.net.

### Ubuntu 14.04

Available in the default repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install converseen
```

### Ubuntu 13.10 and earlier

Not available by default but there is a (probably not dedicated) PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install converseen
```

Answer (score -1):

To show each image for > 1 second, open one of the images and your default image viewer should open. On a fresh install of Ubuntu Eye of Gnome Image Viewer will open.

To start a slideshow:

> Click View ▸ Slideshow or press F5.

Image Viewer will start a slideshow of each image in the folder.

You can customise the slideshow settings, like how many seconds each picture should be displayed for, in the Slideshow tab of Preferences:

> Click Edit ▸ Preferences ▸ Slideshow