# Convert thousands of .pngs to animated .gif, `convert` uses too much memory

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, image-processing, convert

Many of the [questions asking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43763/tool-to-convert-a-sequence-of-numbered-png-files-to-an-animated-gif) [how to create](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380875/loop-terminal-command-for-combining-png-to-gif-animation) [an animated gif](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566476/how-can-i-create-a-gif-out-of-a-sequence-of-png-files-without-the-previous-image) [from a set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460154/mass-conversion-of-images-to-gif) [of png images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457351/are-there-softwares-available-on-ubuntu-for-the-conversion-of-a-series-of-image) suggest to use a variant of ImageMagick's `convert` command:

```
convert -delay 2 -loop 0 *.png animated.gif
```

However, I have **a few thousand images** and thus `convert` uses up all my memory, swap, and then crashes. **What alternative software exists, which is more memory-conscious?** I could use another open format if `.gif` is not supported, and I do prefer a CLI tool.

Comment: How about dividing the *.png files into manageable chunks? Let's say all filenames start with a digit, then `convert -delay 2 -loop 0 0*.png animated.gif` will convert only the files that start with a '0'. And so on.

Comment: @Jos: The files are timestamped and used for a scientific demonstration. Each image delta is 8 sec and we've got a few hours worth of data that must be combined into a single animation.

Comment: @Rinzwind: The computer is fast enough, but at 16 GiB of RAM there is not enough RAM (the problem is swapping). Jos's idea is to avoid the problem, when in fact we do need the final full animation.

Comment: So each .png is in the order of 1 Mb? In that case, all I can think of is to first convert the .png files to a lower resolution or color depth, to make them smaller.

Comment: You say that you could use another open format.  It seems to me that gif isn't exactly the best format for thousands of frames.  Have you considered encoding a video with Ogg Theora instead?

Comment: Each .png is ~65 KiB. I don't know where all the memory is going, that is a detail internal to `convert`.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/), if you really want to use GIF? (Although, as others have said, this isn't what GIF was made for; OGG would be a better choice.)

Comment: Re. "where all the memory is going": 65 Kb is the file size of a compressed image. When uncompressed, the image takes roughly 4 x width x height bytes, so a 1024x768 image would take ~3Mb of RAM. Multiply that by "a few thousand" and you'll see where the memory is going...

Comment: Another consideration is the memory requirements for the resulting GIF: I would expect it to require N x width x height x number of frames (where N is either 1 or 4, more likely 4), so, again, a 1024x768x1000 frames GIF would likely require ~3Gb of RAM to display. The actual filesize would be much less of course.

Answer (score 36):

It sounds like you're trying to make a video. If that's the case, then I'd use a proper video format.

In this case, I'd use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert the individual PNG files to a H.264 video. Since ffmpeg is made to work with videos that can be hours long, it should have no problem with your thousands of images. Using H.264 instead of animated gif will result in a *vast* improvement in image quality.

Something like this should work for you:

```
 ffmpeg -framerate 1/2 -i img%04d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 out.mp4
```

- `-framerate 1/2`: This sets the framerate to one-half FPS, or 2 seconds per frame.
- `-i img%04d.png`: This tells ffmpeg to read the files `img0000.png` though `img9999.png`.
- `-c:v libx264`: Use video codec libx264.

  - You can specify video compression parameters here, if you like:
  - `-crf <number>`: Quality setting. 0 to 51. 23 is the default. 0 is true lossless encoding, which will be quite high bandwidth. 18 is nearly visually lossless.
- `-r 30`: Set the output framerate to 30 FPS. Each of the input images will be duplicated to make the output what you specify here. You can leave this parameter off, and the output file will be at the input framerate, but the resulting movie didn't display properly when I tried it just now.
- `out.mp4`: Output filename.

References:

- [Create a video slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)
- [FFmpeg and H.264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

Comment: Nice expansion of Frantique answer from the day before.

Comment: Here is a simple ffmpeg vs ImageMagick benchmark with concrete test data: https://askubuntu.com/questions/648244/how-to-create-a-gif-from-jpeg-images-with-the-command-line/1102183#1102183

Answer (score 15):

Personally, I would just launch it on limited numbers of files instead of all at once. For example, something like this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Collect all png files in the files array
files=( *png )
## How many should be done at once
batch=50

## Read the array in batches of $batch
for (( i=0; $i<${#files[@]}; i+=$batch ))
do
    ## Convert this batch
    convert -delay 2 -loop 0 "${files[@]:$i:$batch}" animated.$i.gif
done

## Now, merge them into a single file
convert  animated.*.gif all.gif
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `-limit memory 1GiB` to limit the amount of memory `convert` uses.

1000s of images would create a huge GIF that most computers will struggle to display. I keep my animated GIFs below 200 images when possible. The fewer the better. If you number your images, this command will delete the odd numbered images `rm  *[13579].png`.

So here is my typical workflow for creating an animated GIF from a movie scene:

```
avconv -ss 00:26:00 -i someMovie.mpg %5d.png
rm  *[13579].png
convert -limit memory 1GiB -loop 0 -layers optimize -resize 400 *.png output.gif
```

Comment: Thank you, that solution works well. It may also be necessary to increase the allowed memory limits in /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml see https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/396#issuecomment-464070038 for more info

Answer (score 4):

If you have thousands of png-s, the anigif format is weird. I would do it in this way, using `avconv`:

```
 avconv -i "%d.png" -r 25 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p animated.mov
```

Comment: This approach has the added benefit that you could later mux in voice-over or music audio which is impossible with the Graphics Interchange Format.

Answer (score 4):

> I could use another open format if `.gif` is not supported

Perhaps [APNG](https://wiki.mozilla.org/APNG_Specification) is of use to you. It's supported by [some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=apng), including Firefox but at the moment excluding Chrome and IE. Since it's just a PNG extension, it's *very* simple to convert PNGs to APNG. The [apngasm](https://github.com/apngasm/apngasm) tool can do that. But the format is so simple that I recently wrote an APNG assembler myself for Sage. Adapting [that code](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/16571) would be an alternative.

Comment: I'd like to also point out that APNG is non-standard and despite having been around for 7 years is still very obscure.

Comment: For a scientific demonstration, where you might be able to choose the browser used for it, this might still be a simple and robust solution.

Comment: It depends who has to view the demonstration. It wouldn't be very good to hand copies out to the viewers and then two thirds have to go off and download Firefox just to view it. Not the kind of impression I'd like to make if I were making an important scientific demonstration. If it's only intended to be viewed as part of the demonstration then fair enough, but it may not be suitable for other situations.

Answer (score 2):

[gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) is a command-line utility to handle GIF animations. If you are willing to trade memory for speed, you can use its --conserve-memory switch.

Comment: Let me put it this way: gifsicle already has a smaller footprint than ImageMagick - if you find that it still uses too much memory for the task at hand, *then* you can use --conserve-memory

Comment: Ohh, I think I misread what you were saying, that the switch would use more memory, which doesn't make much sense. never mind.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers: since you want to produce a GIF file, I assume you want to display the image on a web page. If so, I would not bother converting your PNGs at all. Just google for "javascript slideshow" and use one of the millions of free scripts. Or write your own, this is really trivial.

The benefits of doing it this way are:

- only one image is loaded in the browser at any time, the slideshow starts fast and does not consume much RAM on the user's machine.
- the solution scales to millions of images. Or billions, if you're patient enough to watch them all :)
- You can add controls to your page to pause, rewind, change the delay or go to a particular frame.

Comment: Thank you Sergey. In fact this is not for display on a webpage. +1 for the idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apng2gif` to achieve the same. From [the man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/apng2gif.1.html):

> ```
> Progrmam apng2gif converts APNG into animated GIF format.
>
>    The Animated Portable Network Graphics (APNG) file format is an extension to the Portable
>    Network Graphics (PNG) specification. It allows for animated PNG files that work similarly
>    to animated GIF files, while retaining backward compatibility with non-animated PNG files
>    and adding support for 8-bit transparency and 24-bit images.
>
>    Default run values are /t 128, no background color. A short syntax hlp is provided without
>    any command line arguments.
> ```

Run the following command to install the package:

```
sudo apt install apng2gif
```

Then run the following command to convert all `.png` files to `.gif`:

```
find -type f -name "*.png" -exec apng2gif {} \;
```